# Is there a performance difference between foo(123) and window["foo"](123)?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there's any performance difference when calling the function `foo()` between `foo(123)` and `window["foo"](123)`.

Comment: Practically: no (although they are _not_ guaranteed to be equivalent, depending on context). It largely comes down to implementation details and one could make a _theoretical_ argument either way. So how to “find out”? Benchmark it! And then realize that such microbenchmarks mean diddly in actual code.. search for “benchmark javascript online” for various tools to make benchmarks easy and shareable.

Comment: `foo(123)` may or may not call `window["foo"]` is that's what you are asking...

Comment: there probably can be a performance difference in edge cases that would never be relevant in a practical scenario.

Comment: You shouldn't care about "performance", if it requires billion operations to find out the difference (I still didn't found it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, 10 loops by 100 million operations gave this (chrome):

[image]

You can notice, that at the 2-nd line it makes some optimizations and starts running faster. Other differences can be neglected.

```js
for( let j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {  
  let start1 = performance.now();
  let x1 = 0;
  for( let i = 0; i < 1e8; i++ ) {
    x1 += foo();
  }
  let end1 = ( performance.now() - start1 ).toFixed(10);
  
  /***/
  let start2 = performance.now();
  let x2 = 0;
  for( let i = 0; i < 1e8; i++ ) {
    x2 += window["foo"]();
  }
  let end2 = ( performance.now() - start2 ).toFixed(10);
  
  console.log("foo():", end1, " // window: ", end2);
}

/***/
function foo() {
  return 1;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh !important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I genuinely expected there to be no difference, but I am seeing the test for `NO_WINDOW` take 2x the time as `WINDOW_STRING` or `WINDOW_PROPERTY` for this simple addition test:

```js
add = (a,b) => a+b;

console.time('NO_WINDOW');

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++);
  add(i, i+1);
  
console.timeEnd('NO_WINDOW');


console.time('WINDOW_STRING');

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++);
  window['add'](i, i+1);
  
console.timeEnd('WINDOW_STRING');


console.time('WINDOW_PROPERTY');

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++);
  window.add(i, i+1);
  
console.timeEnd('WINDOW_PROPERTY');
```

EDIT: Phil pointed out in the comments that this is seems to be a weird issue with `console.timeEnd`, where the first call always takes longer than the subsequent ones.

Reproducing with `performance.now()` and proper benchmarking logic shows no meaningful difference in performance:

```js
add = (a,b) => a+b;
avg = (arr) => arr.reduce(add) / arr.length;

let noWindow = [],
    windowProp = [],
    windowString = [],
    n = 1e6,
    start;
  
  
start = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
  window.add(i, i+1);
windowProp.push(performance.now() - start);


start = performance.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
      add(i, i+1);
    noWindow.push(performance.now() - start);
    

start = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
  window['add'](i, i+1);
windowString.push(performance.now() - start);
  
  
let avgs = [
  avg(noWindow),
  avg(windowString),
  avg(windowProp)
];

console.log(avgs);
```

Comment: The order you run these in seems to make all the difference. Try changing them around and you'll find the first loop always takes the longest

Comment: @Phil That's a great observation, very interesting. Let's try `performance.now()` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's correct benchmark, because while calling the `benchmark(add)` and others in the loop, you are copying the link to that function only once... means inner loop of benchmark (which calls fn) doesn't really matter ( seems? )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME You were absolutely right - I edited and it is an insignificant difference. =)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they're equivalent references, it would seem like the only difference would be in how the variable is read. There have been known to be performance differences in browsers at different points in history when reading globals or object properties using square brackets.

If there is such a difference, it would be negligible, and almost never an issue.

Only thing I would wonder is if some browser loses optimizations for dynamically accessed keys and/or for globals in general. It being a global, and using syntax that dynamically accesses the property, there could be a chance that the function would not get full optimization by the engine.

Again, probably not something that should concern you, unless it's a very heavy function, and quite expensive to run in general.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context in which you call it, it is the same thing. In a browser, essentially you can access any of the keys in the window object without directly referencing it. So any of these are the same:

```
foo(123)
window["foo"](123)
window.foo(123)
```

Read more about the window object and global functions [here](http://All%20global%20JavaScript%20objects,%20functions,%20and%20variables%20automatically%20become%20members%20of%20the%20window%20object.).

Comment: First one is indeed not the same in general... you may want to [edit] to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you use it, yes or no. Essentially, there's no difference used once in a program. [Repeated millions of times, there's a difference](https://jsbench.me/pnkbbjscb2/1), but it depends on where, how, and how many times, that code is executed. It's quite rare you'd look for pure performance, however.